# What is the '%' at the end when I printf my vector?

Tags: c++, macos

I am working on an app and I don't know why when I am printing my vector it shows the numbers "1 2 3 4" and at the end it shows a "%" like "1 2 3 4 %"

I will give you a code example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int n;
vector<int> soldati;

int main(){

    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        soldati.push_back(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < soldati.size(); i++){
        printf("%d ", soldati[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlm32.png) is what is shows when I run it.

I am giving a link because I can't post photos.

Comment: Hmm... couldn't reproduce. [Outputs `1 2 3 ` for me.](https://ideone.com/eiOk2y) What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'%' comes from your shell.

You can add `printf("\n")` at the end to clearly seperate your output and your shell prompt.

Comment: Happy to help. Please upvote and accept the answer (For how-to, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)